# Migrating plugins from Redmine 1.x to 2.x - Javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, redmine-plugins

Sorry about my English. I have migrated plugins to Redmine 2.x, but Javascript functions does not work.
At the top of one of my plugins *show.html.erb*:

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'hgp_markers.js', :plugin => 'hgp_markers' %>
<% end %>
```

hgp_markers.js:

```
function hideEditableMarkers() {
  $$('.edit_marker').each(function(el) {
    el.hide();
    });
  $$('.show_marker').each(function(el) {
    el.show();
    });
}

Event.observe(window, 'load', hideEditableMarkers);
```

And this line with javascript:

```
<%= link_to_function l(:button_edit), "hideEditableMarkers(); $('marker_#{m.id}_row').hide(); $('marker_#{m.id}_row_edit').show(); return false;", :class => 'icon icon-edit' %>
```

What am I doing wrong?
thanks in advance

Comment: define 'does not work'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redmine 2.x (Rails 3.x) switches from Prototype to jQuery. So you need to migrate too.

Thus, `Event.observe` is a Prototype function.

See also: http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/projects/base/wiki/Porting-to-Redmine-2

Comment: Thank you so much Andriy. Any good web for migrating from Prototype to jQuery?